# grunt-mocha-test JSON reporter to a file without console.logs

Tags: json, testing, gruntjs, automated-tests, mocha.js

I'm trying to save all the results of the tests in a JSON file using [grunt-mocha-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-mocha-test)...
I just don't know how to get rid of the console.log outputs, I just need the JSON.
Here is my conf:

```
 mochaTest: {
158             src: ['app/tests/middleware/**/*.js'],
159             options: {
162                 reporter: 'json',
164                 captureFile: './app/tests/results/mochaResult.json',
165                 //quiet:'true',
166                 require: 'server.js'
167             }
168         },
```

Here is an output example:

```
 2 ^[[7m Application loaded using the "test" environment configuration
  3 ^[[0m
  4 connecting to mongodb...
  5 name: localhost
  6 app started on port 3000
  7 successful connection to redis server
  8 {
  9   "stats": {
 10     "suites": 1,
 11     "tests": 5,
 12     "passes": 5,
 13     "pending": 0,
 14     "failures": 0,
 15     "start": "2015-12-23T00:01:43.968Z",
```

What am I missing? is there an alternative approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this as a workaround:

```
grunt.log.header = function () {};
```

I found [this](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/895) link that might have information that helps. There are also packages that have been written to help with this, notably [grunt-log-headers](https://github.com/stevenvachon/grunt-log-headers). Let me know if that works!

Comment: Ultimately what I want is a single JSON file with all the results, but not the console.logs before that.  And yes, the quiet option does include the console.logs into the file. That's the example above